# Optimizar Consulta con servidores vinculados

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta que al ejecutar con una sola base de datos se demora 4 segundos, al hacer el **UNION**  con servidores vinculados esta tarda mas de 4 minutos para devolver los resultados. 
esto se debe realizar con mas de 20 bases de datos

```
SELECT  F0.Cargo,F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Nombre,F0.codbodega,SUM(F0.Neto) AS Total , F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual/2-SUM(F0.Neto) AS Cupo_Disponible, F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual/2 as Cupo_Quincena
    FROM (SELECT T4.nombre AS Cargo, T4.CupoEndeudamientoMensual , T0.fecha,
    REPLACE (RTRIM(T3.nombre),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.NOMBRE1),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO1),'','') as Nombre,
    T1.codbodega,T1.valor,T2.porcentaje,
    CASE WHEN T0.codtipodcto='NC' THEN
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad)*-1,2)
    ELSE
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad),2)
    END AS 'Neto'
    FROM  PRADO.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas T0  
                            INNER JOIN PRADO.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtofacturas  T1 ON T1.consecutivo=T0.consecutivo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN PRADO.PORCIPOS.dbo.tbltarifas_iva     T2 ON T1.codiva=T2.codiva         COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN PRADO.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios  T3 ON T3.codigo=T0.CODIGO         COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN PRADO.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblgrupos_terceros T4 ON T4.codgrupo = T3.codgrupo
WHERE T3.ESEMPLEADO='TRUE'  AND T0.CODTIPODCTO IN ('FA','NC') AND  YEAR(T0.fecha)=2020  AND MONTH(T0.fecha)=01 AND (day(T0.fecha)>=16 AND day(T0.fecha)<=31)  AND T0.codigo='E-1037647327') AS F0
GROUP BY F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Cargo,  F0.Nombre, F0.codbodega

union all 

SELECT  F0.Cargo,F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Nombre,F0.codbodega,SUM(F0.Neto) AS Total , F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual/2-SUM(F0.Neto) AS Cupo_Disponible, F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual/2 as Cupo_Quincena
    FROM (SELECT T4.nombre AS Cargo, T4.CupoEndeudamientoMensual , T0.fecha,
    REPLACE (RTRIM(T3.nombre),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.NOMBRE1),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO1),'','') as Nombre,
    T1.codbodega,T1.valor,T2.porcentaje,
    CASE WHEN T0.codtipodcto='NC' THEN
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad)*-1,2)
    ELSE
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad),2)
    END AS 'Neto'
    FROM  ITAGUI.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas T0  
                            INNER JOIN ITAGUI.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblmvtofacturas  T1 ON T1.consecutivo=T0.consecutivo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN ITAGUI.PORCIPOS.dbo.tbltarifas_iva     T2 ON T1.codiva=T2.codiva         COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN ITAGUI.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblsocio_negocios  T3 ON T3.codigo=T0.CODIGO         COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN ITAGUI.PORCIPOS.dbo.tblgrupos_terceros T4 ON T4.codgrupo = T3.codgrupo
WHERE T3.ESEMPLEADO='TRUE'  AND T0.CODTIPODCTO IN ('FA','NC') AND  YEAR(T0.fecha)=2020  AND MONTH(T0.fecha)=01 AND (day(T0.fecha)>=16 AND day(T0.fecha)<=31)  AND T0.codigo='E-1037647327') AS F0
GROUP BY F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Cargo,  F0.Nombre, F0.codbodega
```

¿Cómo puedo mejorar el tiempo de respuesta?

Comment: Sin saber latencias de red, cuanto tarda cada consulta en cada lugar, y sin tener tu topologia completa, no se que podemos decirte. Esta pregunta asi como esta solo lleva a especulaciones :(

Comment: Como sugerencia (no hay mucho más) trata que las consultas remotas se resuelvan en el servidor de origen, por ejemplo implementando un stored procedure en el servidor remoto que retorne los datos filtrados según los criterios que le pases por parámetro. Luego simplemente invoca a cada Sp en el sevidor dónde corre la consulta principal e inserta los datos en una tabla temporal.

Comment: Puedes crear Vistas Materializadas. Una vez al día, preferiblemente a la media noche, un job debería llenar una tabla local con toda la información de los servidores remotos. Después puedes realizar tus consultas a esa tabla. La desventaja es que la información que obtengas no incluye el mismo día. Ventaja? Reportes de 10 segundos